# angular looping with scope variables in same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 scope variables like the following:

```
 $scope.degrees =[{DegreeCategoryID:"1",DegreeCategory:"Accounting",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"2",DegreeCategory:"Advanced Manufacturing/Mechatronics Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"3",DegreeCategory:"Air Conditioning and Refrigeration Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"4",DegreeCategory:"Auto Body Technology",DegreeCategoryType:"Applied Sciences"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"78",DegreeCategory:"Associate in Sciences",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"79",DegreeCategory:"Associate of Arts in Teaching",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"80",DegreeCategory:"Emphasis",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"},
                {DegreeCategoryID:"81",DegreeCategory:"Field of Study",DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"}];

$scope.degreecategories=[{DegreeID:"1",DegreeCategoryID:"1",Degree:"Accounting AAS ",DegreeTypeID:"2",BHC:"1",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"1",MVC:"1",NLC:"1",RLC:"1",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"2",DegreeCategoryID:"1",Degree:"Accounting Assistant Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"1",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"1",MVC:"1",NLC:"1",RLC:"1",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"3",DegreeCategoryID:"1",Degree:"Accounting Clerk Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"1",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"1",MVC:"1",NLC:"1",RLC:"1",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"4",DegreeCategoryID:"1",Degree:"Advanced Technical Certificate in Professional Accountancy",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"",ECC:"",MVC:"1",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"5",DegreeCategoryID:"2",Degree:"Advanced Manufacturing/Mechatronics Technology AAS ",DegreeTypeID:"2",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"6",DegreeCategoryID:"2",Degree:"Advanced Manufacturing/Mechatronics Technology Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"1",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"7",DegreeCategoryID:"3",Degree:"Air Conditioning and Refrigeration Technology AAS ",DegreeTypeID:"2",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"8",DegreeCategoryID:"3",Degree:"Profit Center Manager Enhanced Skills Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"9",DegreeCategoryID:"3",Degree:"Residential - Technician I Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"10",DegreeCategoryID:"3",Degree:"Residential - Technician III Level II Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"11",DegreeCategoryID:"3",Degree:"Residential AAS ",DegreeTypeID:"2",BHC:"",CVC:"1",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""},
            {DegreeID:"12",DegreeCategoryID:"4",Degree:"Auto Body Metal Technician Certificate ",DegreeTypeID:"1",BHC:"",CVC:"",EFC:"1",ECC:"",MVC:"",NLC:"",RLC:"",Description:""}];
```

Both my above variables are present in the same controller. I am trying to display data in such a way that, when i click a button named 'Academic', it displays all the `DegreeCategoryType:"Academic"` variables from `$scope.degrees` using a filter.(until here it works fine)

Now i wanted to display another list following the previous list based on the selection i make from within the list ie. when i click one selection from the above made list, i wanted to to display the details from my `$scope.degreecategories` such that the it matches and filters based on the `DegreeCategoryID`. How do i approach this issue? i already posted this question but the message i tried to convey was not proper.

Comment: Have you tried making filters on an ng-repeat for the second list, where it filters on something you put in scope?

Comment: here is the plunker of what i am trying. Is there a better approach to this? http://plnkr.co/edit/YLTN0rt9OQMe4E11EkU8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MARKUP Masterlist**

```
        <div ng-show="display.academic" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info list-group list-unstyled" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#panelcategory" data-offset="0" style="max-height:300px;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Academic</h3>
                </div>
                    <a href='#' ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:{DegreeCategoryType:'Academic'}" class="list-group-item">
                      <li ng-click="showAcademic(degree)" >{{degree.DegreeCategory}}</li>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Markup sublist**

```
        <div ng-show="display.academiccourse" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
            <div class="panel panel-info list-group list-unstyled" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#panelcategory" data-offset="0" style="max-height:300px;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{DegreeCategory}}</h3>
                </div>
                    <a href='#' ng-repeat="degree in degreecategories | filter:{DegreeCategoryID:filterSub}" class="list-group-item">
                      <li ng-click="display.appliedsciencescourse" >{{degree.Degree}}</li>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.showAcademic = function(degree){
    $scope.DegreeCategory = degree.DegreeCategory;
    $scope.filterSub = degree.DegreeCategoryID;
    $scope.display.academiccourse = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        <a href='#' ng-repeat="degree in degrees | filter:{DegreeCategoryType:'Applied Sciences'}" class="list-group-item">
                      <li ng-click="display.appliedsciencescourse" >{{degree.DegreeCategory}}</li>
                    </a>
```

I cant see that your ng-click actually does anything. If your ng-click calls a function, applying the element clicked on as a parameter, then you can set $scope.selectedCategory = yourcategory, on your second list, you can filter by selectedCategory, that will exist in the scope.

Comment: i am not sure if i am getting you. Can you help me in the plunker?

Comment: Added another answer, i got it working in the plunker, but had no access to actually change it, so i pasted it in here.

Comment: hi i have one more functionality to add to the code. Can you help me with that as well> i will post a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230434/angular-display-images-when-field-set-to-1